# DeepLearning4j‘s example compiled error

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, maven, deep-learning

I got a few problems while programming with DeepLearning4j.

When I open and compile the example MnistMultiThreadedExample in Eclipse, these problems occured.

```
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MnistDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.test.TestDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.iterativereduce.actor.multilayer.ActorNetworkRunner;**(error)**
import org.deeplearning4j.models.classifiers.dbn.DBN;**(error)**
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.scaleout.conf.Conf;**(error)**
```

It is saying these package are not in the target package. And I couldn't find these modules in the package and couldn't find it in Maven Center Repository while I couldn't find the Class in Source Code.

Now I want to know how I get these modules and what should I do before creating a AutoEncoder which could running on Spark.

The example code is shown below:

```
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.iterator.impl.MnistDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.datasets.test.TestDataSetIterator;
import org.deeplearning4j.iterativereduce.actor.multilayer.ActorNetworkRunner;
import org.deeplearning4j.models.classifiers.dbn.DBN;
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.conf.NeuralNetConfiguration;
import org.deeplearning4j.scaleout.conf.Conf;

public class MnistMultiThreadedExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //5 batches of 100: 20 each
        MnistDataSetIterator mnist = new MnistDataSetIterator(20, 60000);
        TestDataSetIterator iter = new TestDataSetIterator(mnist);
        ActorNetworkRunner runner = new ActorNetworkRunner(iter);


        NeuralNetConfiguration conf2 = new NeuralNetConfiguration.Builder()
            .nIn(784).nOut(10).build();

        Conf conf = new Conf();
        conf.setConf(conf2);
        conf.getConf().setFinetuneEpochs(1000);
        conf.setLayerSizes(new int[]{500,250,100});
        conf.setMultiLayerClazz(DBN.class);
        conf.getConf().setnOut(10);
        conf.getConf().setFinetuneLearningRate(0.0001f);
        conf.getConf().setnIn(784);
        conf.getConf().setL2(0.001f);
        conf.getConf().setMomentum(0.5f);
        conf.setSplit(10);
        conf.getConf().setUseRegularization(false);
        conf.setDeepLearningParams(new Object[]{1,0.0001,1000});
        runner.setup(conf);

        runner.train();

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey folks - thanks for clearing this up about Deeplearning4j. If you have other questions, you're welcome to join us on Gitter: https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j

Answer (score 1):

You should add the following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.deeplearning4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>deeplearning4j-scaleout-akka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This will add as transitive dependencies `deeplearning4j-scaleout-api` and `deeplearning4j-core`. Those three dependencies will provide you the imports you are missing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I downloaded these packages with the version 0.3.2 and the version 0.3.3 and the version 0.3.4. I imported them by version, but the problems still there. I can not fix the problem ... Btw, I get the lib named “dl4j-spark”, it helps me on other problem. :)

Comment: @suanec What do you mean you downloaded them? Did you do it manually? Did you add the dependency is my answer in your POM and in Eclipse did you do "Maven > Update project"?

Comment: I downloaded it from "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/" manually. And I create a common scala project not maven project, so it doesn't have POM and I couldn't Update project while I just do it by myself.... I'm a student, the project is simple, so I package it merely use EXPORT in eclipse.

Comment: @suanec I answered as if you were using a Maven project because your question is tagged Maven. You should download the 3 libraries I mentioned in my answer then.

Comment: I appreciated for your help. I'm satisified by learning the dl4j.